# Getting Emacs to work with GUI in WSL

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x-server

I'm new here and I don't really get this stuff, so I'll try to provide all the relevant details but if something important is missing please tell me.

I have Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2) setup on Windows 10, my Linus version is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I'm also running VcXsrv.

I wanted to run Emacs in graphical display but I'm not being able to do it. I can use Emacs with no problems directly from the bash terminal.

I typed the following:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
emacs
```

And Emacs does open, but in the terminal version, not the GUI. After I close it, I can see in the terminal the message:

```
Display :0 unavailable, simulating -nw
```

I tried searching through the Internet and this site but I couldn't solve this. I have checked that I do have the XServer up and running, at least as far as  I can tell, but the problem seems to reside there somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this link.  I had exact same issue you describe, couldn't get any GUI running.  I needed to ensure that when launching VcXsrv I checked "disable access control", then open up VcXsrv in the Windows firewall, and finally set the DISPLAY correctly using the command sequence shown in link.  Good luck.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/running-wsl-gui-apps-on-windows-10/ba-p/1493242

Comment: Wow that saved me a lot of time: thanks a lot!